# Angle required to rotate a polygon towards the direction of a vector

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, rotations, angle

I have a problem where I need to rotate a polygon so it has the same direction as the vector  $v_1$ (the pointy head face $y$-axis +ve).

I tried a solution where I take two vectors one the $y$-axis: $((0,0), (0, 1))$ and the $v_1((1,1),(2,3))$ and try to find the angle between them to rotate the polygon, but it doesn't seem to be right as the polygon does not face in the direction of the vector. I have tried the algorithms from here [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827393/angles-between-two-n-dimensional-vectors-in-python). Any help would be greatly appreciated 
[Image of the Problem I face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e715M.png)

Comment: What is the center of rotation? What _line_ are you trying to align with the vector? Regardless of the answer to these questions, there’s no need to compute an angle explicitly. A rotation matrix can be constructed directly from that information.

Comment: the center of rotation would be the center of the polygon in this case assume its the origin (0,0)

Comment: OK. Then what exactly are you trying to align with the vector’s direction?

Comment: the head of the polygon(currently the pointy tip facing y axis +ve) to facing the direction of the vector. I need an angle as i need to program it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really must have an explicit angle, then, using the usual mathematical convention that positive angles represent counterclockwise rotations, it’s simply $\theta = -\arctan\frac{v_x}{v_y}$, where $(v_x,v_y) = head - tail$ of your vector. For your example, this would be $-\arctan{2-1\over3-1} = -\arctan\frac12$. If you have an `ATAN2` function available that accepts the numerator and denominator separately, use that to eliminate ambiguities, but be sure that you get the arguments in the right order.

However, if you’re trying to implement this rotation, there’s no real need to compute the angle explicitly (and doing so can introduce extra imprecision). For standard rotation formulas, what you need are the sine and cosine of the angle, not the angle itself. These can be computed directly from the coordinates of the target direction vector: $$\cos\theta = {v_y\over\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}}, \sin\theta = -{v_x\over\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}}.$$ For your example, these work out to be $\cos\theta = 1/\sqrt5$ and $\sin\theta=-2/\sqrt5$.

Comment: sorry if its a stupid question but what would vx represent here?

Comment: @John The difference in $x$-coordinates of the head and tail of your vector; similarly for $v_y$. You want the _direction_ of the vector here.

Comment: Ok i tested your formula and it works great if the head of vector is facing up/ greater than tail but the angle flips if it faces down

Comment: @John Works fine for me in all cases. You’ve either gotten the arithmetic wrong, or you’re using an $\arctan$ function that takes a single argument, which as I mentioned introduces an ambiguity in the angle. If that’s the case, look for a function that takes two arguments or resolve the ambiguity yourself in your code.